# How to make HTML elements react on mouse movements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my question is how can I add specific movement to x-y axis for an HTML element according to mouse movements.

Look at the site here and scroll to second slide:
http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/

How can i achieve such effect!?

Comment: By learning javascript you will achieve such enlightenment that you will in fact be able to actually move an element on the screen while you're watching it!

Comment: This encompasses many, many questions along the way. Start small, prototype, first find out how to track the mouse and build up from there. A complete answer to this questions is just to big for the SO format.

Comment: You can start by learning `event`s in JavaScript, specifically [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousemove).

Comment: fun fact the github 404 page has a similar effect. https://github.com/omgfoobazbar

Comment: @adeneo best profile ever!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to write the library-free version, you will need to start with the following:

Learn DOM-manipulation.

```
var myEl = document.querySelector("#my-el");
```

Learn the `<element>.style` interface.

```
myEl.style.position = "absolute";
```

Learn the CSS properties, their values and how to read/use them from the `style` interface.

```
myEl.style.left = 10 + "px";
```

You'll need to understand the following CSS properties at a minimum:

"display"
"position"
"top"
"left"
"z-index"

Learn how to parse numbers from strings, properly, in JS.
...this will be unimportant, working with the mouse,
but very important, working with the DOM.

Learn how to write event-handlers.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (evt) {/*mousemove event object*/});
```

Learn the properties of event-objects (specifically the event-types that are important, like mouse, keyboard, touch).

Learn how to manage events, and control the number/frequency of operations, based on an ideal framerate, when the browser won't do it for you.

Learn how to make all of these things happen in a cross-browser, IE8+ way.

Learn a little linear-algebra (honestly, learning enough of it to understand an inverted-axis scaled-parallax is just a tiny bit harder than Grade 6 geometry.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a similar effect CSS only, no JS needed!

You can see an example here: [Pure CSS 3D Meninas](http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/meninas.html), by Román Cortés. In his blog, there is also [the explanation](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/3d-meninas-explained/).

Basically, you have to split the target element in small elements, and on hover, set the position of different background layers according to your trigonometric calculations.

From his explanation,

> There are 80 vertical hover elements of 5*455 pixels each, covering
>   the full effect. Each hover element contains inside elements to define
>   every layer position, the background image and the lateral background
>   image. When the hover element is not active (without the mouse over
>   it), all is inside elements showing images are hidden, with display:
>   none.
>
> When the hover element is active, the images are set to display:
>   block, and the position of these are set. These positions have been
>   calculated and are written in the CSS code for each layer and each of
>   the 80 vertical hover elements. This is what does the magic.